# Datadog: enabling RUM allowedTracingOrigins raises CORS errors

Tags: datadog, distributed-tracing, rum

I tried to connect [RUM with backend traces](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/connect_rum_and_traces/?tab=browserrum). In react SPA application I setup a datadog-rum and enabled allowedTracingOrigins option for it, after that our fetch and xhr requests to API started to fail.

How to connect RUM and backend traces properly?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use [datadog-rum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@datadog/browser-rum) version >=2.16,  this one will not cut your custom headers such as Authorization (see. [diff](https://github.com/DataDog/browser-sdk/commit/9ea93ea4b16c0f9d69c40d90aeacc05133c6622c#diff-6b91a2a11175713b7a359be38efe8ceecee6555ae5d1344c784991d40d7a8ea0))
2. Check your server CORS handler. Your server should allow [x-datadog-* headers](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/connect_rum_and_traces/?tab=browserrum#how-are-rum-resources-linked-to-traces) and return them in the `access-control-allow-headers` header